# How can I make a link display only when it does NOT have a class of active?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<a class="active"
    data-ui-sref="exams">
        Exams
</a>
<span class="active">
    Exams
 </span>
```

Is there a way that I can make the link display inline when it does NOT have a class of `active` and make the span display inline ONLY when it has a class of `active`. I think I can use the display property but I am not sure how to make something display when it does not have a class only.

Here I add a bit more to the question as maybe it was not clear. Please note I would like this to display:

```
<a>xx</a>
```

this **not** to display:

```
<a class="active">xx</a>
```

Comment: Try this. `a{display:none;} a.active{display:block;}`

Comment: So you've said "this is not quite right" as a comment to three different answers, all of which are not only entirely correct, but actually the preferred way to do what you want to do, since `:not` is not supported in IE<=8 if that matters, and in my opinion is a bit harder to read. The approach of saying "here's the default (first)", and then "here's a special case (in your case, the active case)", is an absolutely standard CSS best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudo-class [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

Note: This doesn't work for [IE <=8](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot()). Thanks @torazaburo for pointing out.

```css
span {
    color: yellow;
}
span:not(.active) {
    display: block;
    color: red;
}
a {
    display: block;
    color: purple;
}
a:not(.active) {
    display: inline;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
 <a class="active" data-ui-sref="exams">Anchor with class active</a>
 <span class="active"> span with class active</span>
 <a data-ui-sref="exams"> anchor without class active</a>
 <span> span without class active</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check out your answer. I believe it's what I need.

Comment: @torazaburo Sure. I will add that to the answer. I had added a link to MDN where it does mention about the browser compatibility.  Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it by using the display property of CSS.

```css
a .active {
  display: inline;  /*Show when class active is there*/
}

a {
  display: none;    /*Hide when there is no class*/
}
  
span {
  display: none;  /*Hide when class active is not there*/
}

span .active
{
  display: block;    /*Hide when there is active class for the span*/
}
```

Comment: I think this is not quite right. My question was " link display inline when it does NOT have a class of active"

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Hide the link by default */
a {
    display: none;
}
/* Show when it has active class */
a.active {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I think this is not quite right. My question was " link display inline when it does NOT have a class of active".  Maybe the question was confusing which is why I put the NOT in uppercase. Sorry if I was not 100% clear.

Comment: @Alan Think about it--this does exactly what you want. It's cleaner than using `:not` in my opinion (and FWIW `:not` is not supported in IE8).

Comment: @Alan Sorry for the long response time. Sorry I misunderstood - I was confused because `display:inline;` is the default state for a link. If you want it to be display inline only when it does not have a class of "active", all you need to do is set `a.active { display: none; }`. I feel I may still be mis-understanding your request however - as it seems illogical to set `display:none` for class `actiive`.

Comment: Ohhh - sorry. Just caught up on some of the other answers and I understand now. I shouldn't have assumed you wanted `display:none` in place of `display:inline`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

With only css only, I think that this may be what you want :

```
a, span.active {
    display: inline;
}
a.active, span {
    display: none;
}
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vLu88ar/).

Comment: I think this is not quite right. My question was " link display inline when it does NOT have a class of active".

Comment: I think you should reconsider my answer. While it is the case for the two other answer you commented that way, my answer indeed makes your link display inline when it does not have class active, and inline when it has the class active. Just as the answer you selected, but shorter.